# How to group and rearrange the data in python?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, process, stack

I want to use python to process my data. I have a input data that looks like this.[Input data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juDul.png)

And I want the output data to look like this and save it in an excel file or text file for further processing.[Output data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1MkH.png)

I have tried to use groupby method and unstack to solve it but without any success. Any help to achieve this will be highly appreciated. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Please post code and input data format.

Comment: How do I upload the input data? I have it in an excel file.

Comment: use `df.pivot(index='voltage', columns='wavenumber', values=['intensity'])`
https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html#pandas.DataFrame.pivot

Comment: Thank you so much @ericstevens26101. It worked and I learned something new today.